# When I click on each button its shows me the same content of the first button

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, fancybox

I am using a fancy box to display some content. I have managed to put more buttons on my page. But it is not working. For let say when I click on button 2 and 3 I get the same content as in button 1. How to fix this so that when I click on button 2 and 3 I get the right content.

[Content box](http://postimage.org/image/vzdg13sgd/)

[Buttons link](http://postimage.org/image/3w7gjgoxv/)

HTML CODE:

```
   <body>
        <!-- button -->
        <div class="button">
            <p><a href="#bubble" id="pop">CONTENT1</a></p>
        </div>

        <!-- popup -->
        <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="bubble"></a>
        <div class="popup">
            <h2>CONTENT1</h2>
                <p>CONTENT.</p>
                <!-- close -->
                <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
        </div>
```

CSS: CODE

```
header p {padding-top:50px;text-align:center;}
.button a#pop {
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:45%;

    background-color:#444;
    border :0px solid #ddd;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
a#pop:hover {
    border-color: #eee;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
.overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 40%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
}
.overlay:target+.popup1 {
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.close {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: -15px;
    right:-10px;
    width: 30px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.close:before {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    content: "X";
    font-size: 24px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.close:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.popup1 p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How did you add more buttons? Did you repeat the above HTML code or used other way. If you repeat the code it is easy. Just change `<h2>CONTENT1</h2>` for each repeat. Your JSFiddle has only one button. Update your code which has the bug.

Comment: I am building my website with coffeecup. I just repeat the code above 4 times it look like this: [link](http://postimage.org/image/xdwbaioqt/). These are html boxes which you can insert in the program. I have just repeated the code above 4 times changing this <p><a href="#bubble" id="pop">CONTENT1</a></p> and this <h2>CONTENT1</h2> <p>CONTENT.</p> each time when inserting a new html box. But when I click on content2, content3 or content4 it shows me always the content of content1. Changing this <h2>CONTENT1</h2> does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Your link is broken. But anyway I have posted a answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes to your code and manage to fix your issue.

This is what I did;
Remove `top:30%; left:45%;` from **.button a#pop**

Then then change positon from absolute to relative `position:relative;`

And add another button.

```
<div class="button" >
        <p><a href="#bubble2" id="pop">Content2</a></p>
    </div>

    <!-- popup -->
    <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="bubble2"></a>
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Content2</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
            <!-- close -->
            <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
    </div>
```

Note: **href="#bubble2"** and **id="bubble2"** has changed.

This is working fine.

Comment: Wow, this is working. Thanx for the help I was searching and tweaking two days to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I think   your first button **link1's** `<a>` tag area is overlapping the other buttons. That's why you are getting the same content on clicking buttons 2 & 3.Add to  `.button a#pop` css a fixed height similar to the button height so that the `<a>`  covers only the first button.

Comment: Arunu can you give me an example in Jsfiddle I would really appreciate it. Because I had searched two days for the solution...

Comment: It will better if you create a fiddle containing all the three buttons and add it to your question. Others can work on that..

Comment: Aranu here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/VWJ5J/18/. I hope you can help, I have searched two days on the net for the solution even on stackoverflow.